# Redux order of operations

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

Am I guaranteed that the dispatched action will complete before the statement that follows it (which accesses the state that the above action modified):

```
function f() {
  return function( dispatch, getState ) {
    dispatch( myActionCreator() );
    doSomethingWithStateModifiedAbove( getState().x.y.z );
  };
}
```

Or, do I need to turn 'doSomethingWithStateModifiedAbove' into an action creator?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by default, `dispatch()` is 100% synchronous.  By the time that first `dispatch()` call returns, the root reducer function has executed and the state has been updated.  The call to `getState()` will return the updated state.

That said, middleware can intercept, delay, and modify dispatched actions.  It's possible that a middleware might delay the action until later, in which case the first dispatch could would return but not actually result in a state update.  It's still safe to call `getState()`, though.